# I/O , write to a file on a local drive or write to a socket , which one is faster?

Tags: c, sockets

I have a critical application (written in C) that is very performance sensitive.  Writing things to log file will actually slow things down.  I am considering to write the log messages to a socket, which gets send over to another application for logging.  Would that work?

Comment: Yes, it's called `syslog`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog

Comment: Let me answer your question by asking you a question: How long is a piece of string?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to create a separate thread which takes care of the log writing. Just add all log entries to a linked list and let the thread work against that list.

Answer (score 1):

Use asynchronous I/O. This will prevent your application from blocking.

Comment: The AIO API is sufficiently horrible that I'd recommend just using threads instead. It will usually be implemented using threads anyway, and at least if you roll the threads yourself, you can make an API that doesn't suck.

Comment: @R.: For what platform? The OP doesn't specify his.